# Identify this XML format used for a dictionary?

Tags: xml, format

This xml format (fragment below), describes a dictionary. Found in a file with the namespace given as `xmlns:HTML="http://www.w3.org/Profiles/XHTML-transitional"` (and no other namespace or other identifying information given). Does anyone know of any documenation for it, before I attempt to reverse-engineer it?

```
<iosunit id="14942"><unitname id="U14942">formaat</unitname>

<btvt>size</btvt>

<btvt>format</btvt>

<vb>iem. van zijn formaat</vb>

<vbvt>a man of his stature</vbvt>

</iosunit>
```

Comment: The namespace given is for elements and attributes with the `HTML:` prefix, none of which appear in that fragment.

Comment: What other namespaces are included? The tags *btvt*, etc. are not part of the XHTML spec.

Comment: @JayElston - No other namespaces are given. Of course I know those elements are not standard XHTML - if they were I wouldn't need to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Google-fu revealed that [Prisma dictionaries reader](https://gitorious.org/prismadict) has got something to do with that filetype. You should probably contact the project maintainer to get more information.

Comment: Thank you! Your google-fu is clearly superior to mine. This is the sort of thing I was looking for.